# Perguntas cuja resposta são software de terceiros estão no escopo?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Muitas perguntas aqui no site falam do uso de APIs web, como [google-maps](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps), [facebook](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook), [instagram](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/instagram) e [twitter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter), então por exemplo se eu faço uma pergunta como por exemplo:

> Existe alguma alternativa ao Google Maps?

E alguém responde algo como:

> Existe o bing-maps, segue exemplo:
>
> ```
> <script>...</script>
> ```
>
> E existe o here-maps, segue exemplo:
>
> ```
> <script>...</script>
> ```

Isso torna a pergunta off-topic?

Sei que parece estranho essa duvida, mas é que eu respondi a seguinte pergunta no site principal:

- [Como converter vídeo com php sem usar ffmpeg?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113469/3635)

A solução apresentada foi uma API "não tão popular" quanto as do Google, Facebook, etc, o usuário DanielOmine fez um comentário dizendo que a pergunta é *off-topic* por que empresas "desconhecidas" (ao menos foi o que eu entendi do comentário dele).

Argumentei com ele falando que o tamanho da empresa não define questão de on-topic ou off-topic no site, pois se for assim soluções como here-maps que é uma empresa bem menor que google e facebook seria off-topic.

Então ele disse que a pergunta era baseada em opiniões, só que baseado em opiniões não é isso (ao meu ver), pra ser baseado em opiniões ele NÃO pode apresentar nenhum destes "requisitos":

- Fatos:

  Acho que um código que funciona é um "fato", isso a resposta apresenta
- Referências:

  Link para a documentação deve ser uma referencia, acredito eu e a resposta tem links.
- Experiência específica:

  Realmente não tenho experiencia com a biblioteca, mas acho que o significado deste último é para situações cujo a resposta seria algo *"não é possível, pois..."*, no entanto um código é uma maneira de "experimentar".

Eu revisei o https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help todo e nada fala que APIs de terceiros sejam off-topic ou não sejam permitidos por outros motivos em perguntas e respostas, existe algum problema em respostas assim?

Comment: Vejo duas coisas: Se a pergunta não pede uma API, mas as respostas sugerem APIs, nao é culpa de quem perguntou. Se o autor quer uma API, acho irrelevante o "porte" de quem fornece. Inclusive, tem muita API desconhecida que dá de mil a zero no circo de horrores que os peixes grandes fazem volta e meia (se bem que tem uns sites de API feita na marreta que já vi serem usados mais de uma vez no SOpt - api de crawlers "baratos"). Impressão pessoal: acho que a pergunta veio cedo demais pro meta, só tem um voto de fechamento lá.

Comment: @Bacco concordo plenamente e adiciono. Só uma nota: Também não acho que seja culpa de quem responde também, por exemplo é inviável criar um sistema de mapas seu próprio, então a culpa não é de ninguém... Não veio pro meta por causa dos votos, veio por causa de uma discussão entre eu e o Daniel, gosto de fazer esse tipo de pergunta pra deixar claro de como funciona o escopo do site e o modelo ;)

Comment: Tem uma confusão generalizada nesse sentido. O pessoal esquece que tem uma coisa muito mais importante que a regra, que é a intenção da regra. A regra acaba sendo mal usada se você não para pra pensar no motivo dela existir. É igual à ilusão das boas práticas.

Comment: Normalmente eu respondo uma pergunta focando no problema que é apresentado, não na tecnologia que o AP pede (isso quando pede), até para não limitar-se àquela situação em específico. Não vejo problema em sugerir APIs desconhecidas desde que sejam a solução para o que foi perguntado.

Comment: **[editado]** @Bacco me expressei mal, não é bem a regra, mas a ferramenta, por exemplo pra que existe o downvote, tem gente pensando que os veteranos usam para atacar os novatos por maldade então eles começam a dar upvotes em perguntas e respostas ruins (eu vi e ouvi) porque acham que o downvote foi por maldade, quando na verdade o downvote foi porque a pergunta ou resposta tinha mesmo problema. Sei que parece exagero, mas anda surgindo muitos downvotes e upvotes de graça por causa deles discordarem da ferramenta  e do uso.

Comment: Não foi bem isso o que explanei. Aqui do jeito que colocou ficou de um modo muito leviano. Mas não tem problema, tranquilo mesmo. Só que agora não estou com tempo para discussões. Não sou contra explicar sobre API ou software terceiros de nomes/empresas desconhecidas. É que houve um contexto ali naquela situaçlão específica da pergunta. Pois é uma uma pergunta que pede algo muito específico e ao mesmo tempo se naõ for possível, qual seria um outro meio de resolver usando uma API. Como os dois meios são muitos distintos, ficou uma pergunta dupla numa só. Como uma pergunta camaleão.

Comment: Realmente estou sem tempo para detalhar, mas resumindo O AP tinha que abrir uma nova pergunta específica sobre como usar uma API para converter video ou focar a pergunta somente nisso. Se deixar como está, quem for pesquisar terá dificuldade em encontrar pois o título diz outra coisa distinta, sacou? Está bagunçado. Não acho temos o dever em ajustar a pergunta do AP o tempo todo.. O AP tem que saber fazer as perguntas dentro do escopo do site, com um foco definido. Se não tiver esse foco definido, não estiver claro, dificil de entender, desviando para assuntos distintos, eu voto para fechar.

Comment: @DanielOmine discordo do uso do termo *"leviano"*, pra não tornar isto no tom de conflito, vou considerar que você talvez tenha usado a palavra sem conhecer totalmente. De qualquer maneira foi como eu disse: *ao menos foi o que eu entendi do comentário dele*. Espero realmente que entenda.

Comment: @DanielOmine Agora esquecendo isso e indo ao ponto que você citou no ultimo comentário, vou fazer das palavras do Renan as minhas: Normalmente eu respondo uma pergunta focando no problema que é apresentado, não na tecnologia que o AP pede. Se for pra se guiar pela tecnologia citada teria que dividir varias perguntas no site em novas perguntas. O autor pediu uma alternativa ao ffmpeg, na cabeça dele poderia haver duas, ele apenas desconhecia, eu citei a possivel e apenas isto, me focando no problema.

Comment: Não estou lendo toda a discussão, mas a verdade é que: ninguém precisa reinventar a roda. Se existe a solução com uma biblioteca ou API, é uma solução. A questão é quando a pessoa diz que está usando PDO no PHP e alguém aparece dizendo que é melhor usar MySQLi porque não tem esse problema. Isso é off-topic pra mim, nem sempre temos liberdade de escolha das bibliotecas, coisa comum na vida de programador, mas se não foi pre-estabelecida uma biblioteca, oferecer uma não me soa nada de errado. Exemplo disso é a pergunta sobre como abrir um executável a partir de um resource na memória do Delphi.

Comment: @DH. não entendi bem, o que seria off-topic pra você? A pergunta citada? Se entendi o seu pensamento é parecido com o do Renan, não importa bem a tecnologia (existe exceções), o que importa é a solução, seria isto o seu ponto de vista?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Quando a pessoa diz que está tendo problema com uma biblioteca específica, dizer pra ela usar outra biblioteca seria off topic, a menos que quem perguntou esteja sendo bem específico que aceita outras. Se ela precisa de qualquer coisa pra resolver um problema, recomendar uma lib/API é uma solução válida on topic. O SOpt não se restringe a pedir bibliotecas como é o caso do SOen e vários outros sites da SE.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O exemplo que dei sobre o Delphi e aplicativos em memória é que não precisa explicar qual das centenas de Handles do Windows tu precisa passar pa executar um exe sem ter um arquivo, como usar um BinaryStream em Deplhi que não é nem esse o nome da classe, etc. A pessoa quer saber como abrir o programa em memória, com ou sem biblioteca, ela só quer a solução. A resposta aceita é um fonte um ano mais velho que a pergunta, que veio dos confins do google. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395493/execute-an-exe-file-from-resource-into-memory

Comment: Ah sim entendi o seu ponto de vista @DH. Mas eu não vi pedido pra biblioteca especifica na pergunta, então estou sem entender bem aonde isso se encaixa, outra coisa, não querendo discordar, o que é off-topic no site são as "perguntas", já as respostas tem e sempre tiveram boa aceitação por parte da comunidade que poderiam haver situações alternativas, mas que solucionam o problema. Só um detalhe, não confunda Stackoverflow.com com Stackoverflow.com.br cada comunidade tem a sua cultura ;)